# Planet tilts and rotations.

Tags: pyephem

We are building an Astronomical clock that tracks the planet and moon locations in the Galilain solar system ( planets out to Saturn And moons do earth and 4 moons of Jupiter.  Think if an orrery that acuately tracks time.

The clock can move to different epoch and Can move through the 12 astronomical ages.  It’s 8ft in diameter, hangs from the ceiling,  24 stepper motors drive the rotations and tilts of the planets,  18.6 year moon cycle etc.

We plan to use PyEphem to identify locations of planets.  We need additional data and was wondering if python can provide this data.

We need the rotation and tilt of planet (earth mars Saturn). And we need tie rotation so the part of the planet that faces the sun.  Lastly we need to Jupiter’s 4 major moons location over the planet.

Does PyEphem support these addition items and if not is there any advice you can provide us. 
W

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Details of what PyEphem supports are available from the [PyEphem website](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/index.html) which provides detailed, searchable documentation.

This is very standard for software libraries. I am not being disingenuous when I advise you to RTFM - this is definitive material. Google and Bing should be your next port of call, especially since you have clearly defined search terms.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, PyEphem does not include any models of planetary rotation, no — so the lack of any mention of it in the documentation is not an omission but the lack of that feature in the underlying `libastro` library.